# Como hacer un select de React más alto

Tags: html, css

Tengo un formulario en `React`, pero en el `select` no se alcanza a distinguir el texto, mi pregunta es, si se podría hacer un poco mas alto para que se vea mejor

[image: Select más pequeño que el alto del texto]

Este es el código:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<select className="form-control" value={data.id_sucursal} onChange={this.handleChange}>
  <option value="0" selected>--Seleccione sucursal--</option>
</select>
```

Comment: segura que no quisiste decir más alto en vez d emás ancho?

Comment: Si, perdón, me confundí un poco :)

Comment: Tienes código como para poner un [mcve] ?

Comment: @RuslanLópez Si ya lo añadí

Comment: como verás no se puede reproducir, podrías intentar agregarñle tus estilos o el componente padre

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque no contiene un ejemplo mínimo, si bien publico un poco de codigo no corresponde al problema.

Comment: El problema no es de react es de `css`, podrias indicar si utilizas alguna libreria o es tu propio select. mostrar el codigo css de la clase `form-control`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

puedes agregar lo siguiente dentro de tu etiqueta select:

```html
<select className="form-control" value={data.id_sucursal} onChange={this.handleChange} style="height: 50px">
  <option value="0" selected>--Seleccione sucursal--</option>
</select>
```